# How can I check if on specific plugin generated page or child

Tags: plugins, redirect, bbpress

I am writing a function to force a redirect when accessing a certain page.

I have done similar things using code like

```
 if ( is_main_query() && 
       ( is_singular($restricted_post_types)||is_single() ) 
       && ! is_user_logged_in() ) { 
           wp_redirect(...) 
 }
```

But now I want to target a certain class of pages (profile related pages in the bbpress plugin bc Genesis is destroying them). I don't know what I can use to identify this from an action in the template_redirect hook.

I think anything with the pattern `'<baseurl>/forums/user'` would catch what I need

Comment: What do you mean by "Genesis is destroying them"? Genesis is removing those pages?

Comment: not rly sure why but it's removing most of the markup. twentytwelve theme: http://imgur.com/HJKeRg3  vs  base genesis: http://imgur.com/SMcmKvS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to catch the pattern '/forums/user', you could use PHP's stringpos function.  Something like this should capture what you're looking for:

```
$url_pattern = "/forums/user";
$requested_uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

if(strpos($requested_uri, $url_pattern) == 0){
    //Your code goes here
}
```

Make sure if you have "enforce trailing slashes" set that you use "/forums/user/" as your matching pattern instead.  This code isn't tested but should work.